# Mac Pro 5.1 Catalina boot picker does not work

Tags: startup

I have two separate drives one with Catalina 10.15.7 and one with Windows 10. The Boot picker worked fine, but now I can't seem to get it to start.

I tried to open it by pressing the options key (I'm using a Windows keyboard so I use the alt key) when starting the Mac. Pressed the keys before the start sound, after and during. This results into a black screen while the GPU fans are turned on, normally they would stop spinning. Keyboard is definitely on. If I release the alt key in this state nothing happen.
I also tried to plug my keyboard into every USB port available and unplugged everything else.
Other key combinations (Recovery mode,...) work.

Comment: I presume you have a Mac-flashed graphics card in there & can normally see the screen before login? How long have you had Catalina on it? Was it working OK before now, on Catalina? Did you use DosDude to install it initially? Did you have Mojave on there prior to Catalina, so you got the firmware update necessary for the GPU to init properly? btw, I have a few of those old Pros, not all of them will respond properly to a wireless or Windows keyboard at boot. I have to go get a real Apple wired keyboard.

Comment: My graphics card is a radeon rx580. I installed Catalina yesterday with DosDude and since then it does not work. Prior to Catalina Mojave was on there.

Comment: The 580 is fine - but is it Mac flashed & could you always see the boot screen right from the start, or did you have to wait until you got to the login screen? Is FileVault enabled?

Comment: The card is not flashed, I always need to wait until the login screen. FileVault is enabled.

Comment: That's your issue then. You cannot use FileVault with a non-flashed graphics card. if you can get through to Catalina itself, disable it & give it time to completely decrypt before trying again.

Comment: idk how authoritative this is - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8581932 but the filevault issue has become 'common knowledge'. Of course, as Apple don't officially support much of this, some of it's guesswork. This one says the RX series can't be flashed. All mine run HD7950, which are flashed.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language. Mixed up enabled and disabled. FileVault is disabled.

Comment: Ah, OK. Have a look at this, which explains a lot of things that won't work in Mojave/Catalina without the right GPU. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/upgrade-gpu-on-5-1-filevault-boot-screen.2181938/ I've never tried any of this myself, I've just heard too many scary stories about lack of stability on these Pros past Mojave to have ever wanted to try it myself. Basically, if you can't see the boot screen, you can't choose another boot device except from within the OS itself.

Comment: Bratl: Is the question that you have no way to switch between macOS and Windows? Or, is the question just about not being able to use the "boot picker" (Mac Startup Manager)?

Comment: @DavidAnderson - I'd go with "how to switch OS" if you have a nice answer for that, as the boot picker is not going to happen.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Originally the question was about not being able to use the startup Manager anymore. I had the plan to update to big sur, thats why I need it.

Comment: If you can boot to recovery, why can you not choose which operating system to boot from recovery?